# Construct a weighted graph such that each edge between node u and v is 1 if (u is divisible by v or v is divisible by u) else the weight is n+1

Tags: c++, graph-theory, depth-first-search, shortest-path

You are given an integer n which is the numbers of nodes in the graph. The weight of the edge will be:

- weight of edge between u->v  = 1 if (u is divisible by v or v is divisible by u)
- weight of edge between v->u  = n+1 if( u is not divisible by v)

You are given q queries and we need to find the shortest distance between them.

I tried the problem but the only problem I am facing is how am I suppose to construct the weighted  graph using the given condition because N <= 10^5 I can't traverse the whole graph again and again and make edge if they are dividable by each other on the other hand if I try to find the shorted path for each query still that doesn't seems to be  feasible because Q <= 10^3.

Here is an example for better explanation

N=6
Q=2 {(1,3),(3,4)}

Here is how the graph would look like

```
U -> V = weight
1->2=7
1->3=7
1->4=7
1->5=7
1->6=7
2->4=1
2->6=1
3->6=1
```

So the answer for the query will be

```
for (1->3) = 7
for (3->4) = 3->6->2->4 = 3
```

Comment: Why for 1->2 the weight is 7? 2 is divisible by 1 right?

Comment: *"how am I suppose to construct the weighted graph"* -- you're not supposed to. Someone dressed up a math question in the guise of a graph question, hoping to trick people into wasting time trying to construct the graph.

Comment: Your setup is inconsistent. According to the first rule, the edge `6->2` has weight 1 because 6 is divisible by 2. According to the second rule, the edge `6->2` has weight n+1 because 2 is not divisible by 6. Tough to be both unless n is zero.

Comment: I mean, the answer looks like 1 or 2.  But the specification is inconsistent, so could be 1 or n+1.  You do not appear to understand the problem enough to even describe it.

Answer (score 0):

To construct a graph with the specified edge weights.

Assume you have a graph class with a method for adding edges

vpod AddEdge( int src, int dst, int weight );

then

```
LOOP u from 1 to N
    LOOP v from u+1 to N
        weight = 7
        IF ( u % v == 0 || v % u == 0 )
            weight = 1
        graph.AddEdge( u,v, weight );
```